# What is Port 31338 And why is it always Open?

Tags: ports

> -snip-< Success! Port 31338 Is Open!
>
> -snip-< Added -snip- to the -snip-
>
> -snip-< TIP: -snip-
>
> -snip-< Failiure :( Port 31339 Is Closed!
>
> -snip-< Added -snip- to the -snip-
>
> -snip-< TIP: -snip-
>
> -snip-< Failiure :( Port 31340 Is Closed!
>
> -snip-< Added -snip- to the -snip-

This is my output in my richtextbox with my program.
What is Port 31338 and why is it always open?

Does it have any relations with Port 31337? (Note: '-snip-' just means I cut out some information.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be anything, but that port is [sometimes used by Back Orifice, an old and nasty Trojan that's having a bit of a renaissance, as well as some other nasty software](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/which-backdoors-live-on-which-ports/8/4). I would strongly suspect an infection and run a malware scanner immediately.

Comment: Thats really scary. I tested 3 IP's (2 different locations on my vpn and one of my friends) and they were all open. Crazy..... I will accept your answer when it lets me.